# How to encode a path that contains a hash?

Tags: c#, url, uri

How do you properly encode a **path** that includes a **hash (#)** in it? Note the hash is not the fragment (bookmark?) indicator but part of the path name.

For example, if there is a path like this:

http://www.contoso.com/code/c#/somecode.cs

It causes problems when you for example try do this:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/code/c#/somecode.cs");
```

It would seem that it interprets the hash as the fragment indicator.

It feels wrong to manually replace # with %23. Are there other characters that should be replaced?
There are some escaping methods in Uri and HttpUtility but none seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did some more digging friends and found a duplicate question for Java:
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

However, the .Net **Uri** class does not offer the constructor we need, but the **UriBuilder** does.

So, in order to construct a proper URI where the path contains illegal characters, do this:

```
// Build Uri by explicitly specifying the constituent parts. This way, the hash is not confused with fragment identifier
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http", "www.contoso.com", 80, "/code/c#/somecode.cs");

Debug.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri);
// This outputs: http://www.contoso.com/code/c%23/somecode.cs
```

Notice how it does **not** unnecessarily escape parts of the URI that does not need escaping (like the :// part) which is the case with HttpUtility.UrlEncode. It would seem that the purpose of this class is actually to encode the querystring/fragment part of the URL - not the scheme or hostname.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few characters you are not supposed to use. You can try to [work your way through this very dry documentation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), or refer to this [handy URL summary on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url).

If you check out this very website, you'll see that their C# questions are encoded `%23`.

[Stack Overflow C# Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c#)

You can do this using either (for ASP.NET):

```
string.Format("http://www.contoso.com/code/{0}/somecode.cs", 
    Server.UrlEncode("c#")
);
```

Or for class libraries / desktop:

```
string.Format("http://www.contoso.com/code/{0}/somecode.cs",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("c#")
);
```

Comment: Please note that encoding the entire URL this way (including scheme and path) actually yields a string that is not a valid URI. It throws Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined if you try constructing a URI from it.

Comment: I think the point is missed here. It's not *just* about the # character, but rather, how to construct an arbitrary URI with a valid path that might contain any of the invalid characters.

Comment: @Dodgyrabbit given that we don't know which parts of the URL are dynamic, I have left it to the OP to decide where it is appropriate to use the utility class.

Comment: I dont think that System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode gets rid of the # sign, i just tried it and its still there, this truncating the query at the server side.

Comment: @Ted it results in C%23 - how were you testing the value?

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. I tried a C# client (WebClient), but when received at the server it was truncated after where the # is. However, if I look at the string on the client side, the # is indeed "gone", but .NET on the server-side seem to UrlDecode it "behind the scenes" and then it truncates it before the code is executed (the C# code, implementing the method)

Answer (score 3):

Use [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx): `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://www.contoso.com/code/c#/somecode.cs";
        string enc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

        Console.WriteLine("Original: {0} ... Encoded {1}", url, enc);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The string enc in the example, although escaped, is no longer a valid URI. Try Uri uri = new Uri(enc) and you'll see it throws Invalid URI exception. Found the correct solution though.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm a bit confused by the MSDN documentation, then, which says _Encodes a URL string. The UrlEncode method can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values._ (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)