# Error when pass a directory path

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

In start page: I want to pass a directory path to a popup window page when client click on LinkButton `lbtnEditText`

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="lbtnEditText" runat="server" Text="Edit Text" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Path") + "," + Eval("Name")%>' OnCommand="Button1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] values = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');

        string queryString =

            "editpage.aspx?path="

            + values[0];

        string newWin =

            "window.open('" + queryString + "');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

            (this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);

    }
```

The `queryString` exactly is = `"editpage.aspx?path=D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\profile.xml"` (I check it when I debug)

But In destination page (popup window): `editpage.aspx`

```
    string path = Request.QueryString["path"];
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
    if(content!=null)
      textarea.Value = content;
```

It has an error: `Could not find file 'D:\C#Projects\website\C`
Try to debug, the `path` I recieved is just only : `"D:C"`

And in the address bar of `editpage.aspx` display:

`http://localhost:41148/website/editpage.aspx?path=D:C#ProjectswebsiteLecturergiangvienprofile.xml`

Help!!! Why is the path changed when I pass it to the editpage???

Comment: have a look at url encoding

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode a path that contains a hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319656/how-to-encode-a-path-that-contains-a-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you the actual solution for C#:

```
string queryString = "editpage.aspx?path=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[0]);
```

see reference for encoding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx

and decoding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your solution and detail link. That's a nice help. Thank again

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind happening so is :: you are passing query string data which is having unexpected characters which are '\,#'.
The solution to this is escape and encode this values before setting as query string values

Answer (score 2):

Encoding Urls correctly is unfortunately required skill for anyone doing web development...

Everything after `#` is "hash" portion of Url and browser don't need to send it to server. More formal name is [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

What you need to do is encode value of `path` query parameter correctly (i.e. with `encodeURIComponent` funcition in JavaScript).

Comment: I've never known about encodeURIComponent before, can you give me a example. Thank in advance