# Java Android Illegal Argument exception

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I'm executing the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("(...)&avatarUrl={(...)}&socialId=1&sexo=m&username="));
```

My problem is I'm getting an `illegalArgumentException` at letter l from the word `avatarUrl`, and I don't understand why.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter be preceded with an `?` ??

Comment: @blo0p3r This might simply be the answer.

Comment: If so please accept the answer so we can stop looking :)

Comment: The fisrt parameter starts with an ?. I used (...) to shorten the url

Comment: If the suggestions answers below do not work out, please do post the full URL (but maybe with a different domain name).

Comment: http://bn.com/DarPerfasdfil?email=&id=5078789059&socialId=1&avatarUrl={"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/161422_507789789789059_666973_q.jpg"}}&sexo=m&username=

Comment: Just in case I change the domain name.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass that whole string in JSON-syntax as your avatarUrl and no only the "url" part? Also, consider my complete answer below to avoid encoding issues. For instance, braces should be escaped as praseodym pointed out below.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the question of `?` oder `&` in your code, there are cleaner ways to pass parameters:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

params.setParameter("avatarUrl","...")
      .setParameter("socialId","...")
      .setParameter("sexo","...")
      .setParameter("username","...");

request.setParams(params);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

*(not tested, but should work)*

**Note: I heavily edited my original answer due to a little misunderstanding.**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code of HttpGet](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0/httpclient-4.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.java?format=ok), this exception means that the URL is invalid:

1. The first query string parameter should be preceded with `?`
2. `{` and `}` are [not valid characters for URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) and should be escaped