# what this url means and how it works?

Tags: php, http, web

I saw some request like

```
www.example.com/start.php?404;http://www.example.com:80
```

but unfortunately can't understand if it is a valid url or how it will work.

Comment: So what is the result of the page? I think there is probably some URL rewriters on the server for URLs like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`www.example.com/start.php?404`*

and

*`http://www.example.com:80`*

and

*`www.example.com/start.php?404;http://www.example.com:80`*

are all valid URLs. But since `;` is not a `reserved symbol`, it needs to be URL encoded. See [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) for the list of characters allowed in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a valid url. It redirects you to a 404 page. The http://www.example.com:80 is probably wrong set so it enters a complete url at the end of the already standing url.

Maybe i am wrong.