# What characters could I use in the URL's path?

Tags: url, syntax, character, uri

I notice the other day that you can access Google Plus from http://google.com/+, which had me wondering what other characters could be used in a URL's path. So, I figured I'd ask here: What characters *could* I use and what *should* I use (some might not be available in older browsers as an example)?

Remember, I'm only talking about the URL's *path*. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you even search for an answer first?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think it's a dupe, please link to it.

Comment: @Leeish A little bit...

Comment: I'm asking only regarding the path part of a URL, not the full URL scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The authoritative reference is Internet-standard STD 66, *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*, which is currently RFC 3986. Clause [3.3 Path](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-3.3) specifies the characters allowed.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to alphanumerics and the reserved characters that have special meaning like ? and & you may use "$-_.+!*'(),".

See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html for details.

Similar question and answer here: [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Comment: RFC 1738 was obsoleted, as regards to generic syntax issues like this, in 1998 by RFC 2396, which in turn was obsoleted by RFC 3986.

Comment: You are right, RFC 1738 was updated (not obsoleted though) by RFC 2396 and later RFC 3986. Didn't check that sorry. If I understand clause 3.3 correctly it is still allowed to use the mentioned characters though? Referred to as sub-delims?