# CodeIgniter - URI Disallowed Characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, config

I had issue of @ which I added in $config['permitted_uri_chars'] as you can see below:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@\-';
```

BUt here is my URL

http://mydomain.com/awarenessroom/facebook_image_share/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5lanVpY3lzb2x1dGlvbnMuY29tL3Jla2xhaW1wYWtpc3Rhbi5jb20vdXBsb2Fkcy9hd2FyZW5lc3Nfcm9vbS9pbWFnZXMvOTEwNzA4ODI3VG9yIERheSBaYW5qZWVyLmpwZw==

and it says "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.", even if I add = in config, still not working. Can anybody let me know what is required exactly by CI in config to get resolved for URI to be working?

Comment: Don't you need A-Z too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url

Comment: the `==` at the last you need to user url encode if you plan passing it to the uri.

Comment: are you encoding some string for the url........

Comment: I think you are encoding some thing so use this rtrim(base64_encode($string_name),'=')

Comment: sending this url after base64_encode

Comment: @Umer use the above one which i specified while encoding....

Comment: @Venkat: why would you `rtrim()`?

Comment: because in the end to remove those '==' when you encode any string using base64_encode right side you will get '==' those are not allowed in url thats why...

Comment: venkat, = cannot be removed which are appended by base64_encode. After excluding = for the sake of URI to be working, we will not be able to get exact value using base64_decode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your info you are using base64_encode so this i will suggest to you because i am following the same in my web application

```
$encode_string = "google.com";

$result = rtrim(base64_encode($encode_string ),'=');

$decoded_string = base64_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `url_encode(base64_encode(string))` and then decode it. It will help you for sure.

Answer (score -1):

use `url_title()` function

from this linkl  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html