# Issue with URL in Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm working on an application that plots map route based on inputs. Here's a sample input URI:-

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=38.842794,-77.408132&destination=38.8685938,-77.2711787&region=en&sensor=true&waypoints=optimize:true|38.839619,-77.410309
```

Using httpget,httpresponse I plan to get the response from the URI in json.
I'm having an issue with this link.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity!=null)
            {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                StreamToString st = new StreamToString();
                result = st.convertStreamtoString(instream);

                blah blah blah ...
```

I'm getting an error saying:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 160: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=38.842794,-77.408132&destination=38.8685938,-77.2711787&region=en&sensor=true&waypoints=optimize:true|38.839619,-77.410309
```

So I thought it might have occurred since I did not encode the URI. So later I tried using

```
uri = URLEncoder.encode(uri, "UTF-8");
```

Then I've been getting a different error saying:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=38.842794,-77.408132&destination=38.8685938,-77.2711787&region=en&sensor=true&waypoints=optimize:true|38.839619,-77.410309
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't count, but do you suppose that the | in  "...true|38.839619..." is causing the issue?

Comment: I don't think that would have caused the problem as I do have an another code which does not have lat,lng but instead string addresses and it did work for that code.

Comment: I agree with Martin. I didn't think | was a legal URL character. Could be wrong but my editor agrees that | is at index 160 :) I skimmed through this, but it looked solid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url

Comment: My original guess would have been the colon in "...optimize:true|38.83..." though (Thought this was a reserved URL char)

Comment: Thanks to Martin and Thynk Apps. Your answer has got me the result.

Comment: I've been getting the second kind of error as I was trying to encode the colon too by using uri = uri.replace(":", "%3A"); which is not necessary at all.

Comment: Can you post the result as an answer so I could mark it as solved and give you the credit!

Comment: I'm having the same issue ! What was the solution???