# Chromecast - URL format

Tags: ios, chromecast

According to this post: [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url), () are allowed in URLs. But when I try to feed a URL with a pair of parenthesis in it to chromecast, chromecast couldn't find the file specified by the URL and displays nothing but a black background on the big screen. But things work well if I remove the parenthesis or substitute with square brackets. So are () not allowed in a URL for chromecast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode "(" and ")" (use `%29` and `%28`), [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) (2005) supersedes 1738 (1994) which is referenced in the post you had mentioned.