# How to prevent Google Chrome and IE substituting '|' in URL with %7C

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, url, percent-encoding

We have adapted an old website to use semantic URLs and - for a number of reasons - are unable to use a `/` as a seperator. Instead, we are using `|` as our seperator.

For example:

```
www.example.com/page|sub-page1|sub-sub-page2
```

Everything is working fine with only one small problem. Google Chrome and IE are displaying the URL as:

```
www.example.com/page%7Csub-page1%7Csub-sub-page2
```

We are using `&#124;` to encode our `|` seperator but Chrome and IE are still substituting with `%7C`.

Firefox and Safari display the URL correctly!

Comment: And since encoding `|` as `%7C` in an HTTP URL context is totally _correct_, your complaint is what now exactly …?

Comment: 1.We're concerned that copying the URL with %7C might cause problems when placed on other sites; 2.It makes the URLs difficult to read which kind of defeats the purpose of using semantic URLs!

Comment: 1. You should be equally concerned that using an _unquoted_ `|` in your URLs might also cause problems the other way around, 2. well then don’t use non URL-safe characters in your “semantic” URLs in the first place!

Comment: Our choices are limited. I wish we could be using '/' but that is unfortunately out of the question. Is there no solution to stopping '|' being substituted. Firefox AND Safari displays '|' correctly!

Comment: Having `|` _un-encoded_ in an URL _is_ technically not correct. Browsers are so fault-tolerant however, that they usually apply the missing encoding for you if you have them in link URLs not encoded. What browsers make of it when they _display_ them in the address bar is a different matter (keyword [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier)) – but I don’t think you can _force_ anything here if the browser just doesn’t want to play along.

Comment: See also (same OP): [Is '|' a recommended seperator for semantic URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22790773/1591669)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. guys. We'll find another separator!

Comment: presently browsers from the Firefox and Chrome family remove | and %7C from the URL queries. They remain only when they were entered manually in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in your comment "We'll find another separator".

You might want to take a look at [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856809/1967396) which describes exactly what characters are allowed in what part of the URL.

From this, you can see that the characters you are free to use "at will" are

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

It seems to me that of all these characters, the `~` is the only one that could reasonably take the place of your `|`.

Comment: Thanks Floris. I've sometimes seen commas being used (www.example.com/page,sub-page1,sub-sub-page2). What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @richardTinkler the comma is not in the unreserved list. Even though you can get away with it. Go with what you think looks better.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way HTML encodes their URLs and it so happens that the character %7C is the encoded version of "|" so basically just use ~.