# Symfony2 special chars in route path

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Symfony2 by default displays entity details by ID

```
 /**
 * Finds and displays a State entity.
 * @Route("state/{id}", name="state_show")
 * @Template()
 */
```

I'd like to display name of the state, but most of states contains special chars (Polish special chars).

Links work if I use {name} but it is safe to use special chars in link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Characters allowed in a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Comment: Question is more about how to change special chars to regular chars in Symfony than which chars are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Gedmo extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md) for that, especially [Sluggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not going to encode the URL, characters other than the following are unsafe.

- alphanumeric,
- Reserved `";", "/", "?", ":", "@", "=", "&"`,
- Special characters: `$-_.+!*'(),`.

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way (also for SEO) is to change polish letters to standard ones (for example ł => l, ą => a) and use - as words separators