# ognl array values as GET parameters

Tags: http, struts2, ognl

I have an application using struts2-ognl. I have an array of strings and it gets populated by GET parameters in the request. Like the following example

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/myAction.action?myArray[1]=value1&myArray[2]=value2 etc etc
```

Is there any way to instruct ognl that for arrays I don't want to use "[" or "]" but another set of characters ( let;s say for example "(" and ")" so the url could work like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/myAction.action?myArray(1)=value1&myArray(2)=value2 etc etc
```

I'm asking this because "[" and "]" are url reserved characters. I have tried to urlEncode them but then ognl ignores those parameters.

Comment: What issues do you have with `[...]`?

Comment: IIRC you don't even need the `[]`, you can just have multiple `myArray=xxx` parameters, too.

Comment: ...if it isn't some object property.

Comment: url reserved?! where did you get that?

Comment: @AleksandrM Users reach my server through a secured infrastracture from Cisco that blocks urls that do not follow the standards. I can't reduce the security level, as security is point #1 in the app.

Comment: @DaveNewton of course I need [] . Without them you can only populate simple objects or arrays.. For arrays in my case you need [] to show the index ( I pass specific index for each parameter ). Also most times I populate Map<String,String>.

Comment: @RomanC Check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url

Comment: @Panos Or lists; S2 will structure multiple params with the same name. It'll actually do them in order, too, but passing a specific index is fine--no need to be snippy about it.

Comment: @Panos I thought `[]` are well supported in query string.