# Why mailto body does not recognize object literal as part of the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object literal

```
var object = {
    test: "test";
}
```

I call JSON.stringify on this object and append it to a query string

```
http://example.com?parameter={"test":"test"}
```

But when I append this query string into the mailto body, only this part

```
http://example.com?parameter=
```

got wrapped as an hyperlink while the rest is showed as plain text.

what I did was this:

```
window.location = "mailto:someone@example.com?subject=subject&body=http://example.com?parameter={"test":"test"}";
```

And when the email client view showed, only the part before '=' got wrapped as hyperlink.

Comment: You mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/m13gx7dx/

Comment: @jmartins not really, I will update the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6spq3p7n/

Comment: @jmartins could you try and insert the url into the mail body?

Comment: *cough* [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) *cough*

Comment: @jmartins http://jsfiddle.net/Franktian/ev7u5d1n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application that renders the emails just doesn't consider `{` as part of a url, you can try encoding it. It wont look pretty though.
Something like

```js
window.location = 'mailto:someone@example.com?subject=subject&body=' + encodeURIComponent('http://example.com?parameter=' + encodeURIComponent('{"test":"test"}'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually related to accepted characters on URL. You should check this answer here: [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

So your link will work if you change this " to this ':

```
window.location = "mailto:someone@example.com?subject=subject&body=http://example.com?parameter={'test':'test'}";
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s518b12p/) to replace quotation marks

Comment: That's not it, it's the `?` and `=` in the `body` parameter. Can't parse a query string without those being encoded.

Comment: @BradChristie works fine for me in multiple browsers

Comment: @BradChristie Actually, now they are automatically encoded by the browser. Try it on chrome. `mailto:someone@example.com?subject=subject&body=http://example.com?parameter={'test':'test'}`

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly. But here, the problem is only this quotation mark "". Because it is not encoded by the browser.

Comment: So relying on the browser to fix the problem for you instead of following the age old protocol is the answer. ... doesn't seem like right answer.

Comment: It isn't the best. That's why I voted up for the other solution, it's better with encodeURIComponent