# Regex to find hashtags, mentions and links

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract from a string all the hashtags (#hashtag), mentions (@user) and links.

Right now I'm using this one:

```
@"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|#|@|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)";
```

But it doesn't recognize users that starts with _ like "@_me" and links like this one (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/12/03/whats-new-for-windows-10-iot-this-fall/#.VmB1q2NPg2A.twitter) are recognized partially.

How can I improve my regex to get all the possible cases?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Possible alternative route: use `IndexOf` on `#` or `@` to use as a starting position and then find the first space after it?

Comment: @sab669 That could work but wouldn't a regex be more efficient?

Comment: @KonstantinZadiran My question is how can I improve this regex to get all the possible cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern (remember to turn `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option on):

```
(?'tag'(@|\#)(\w|_)+)
|
(?'link'((https?://)|(www\.))[\w$-_.+!*'(),]+)
```

For this string:

> My name is @_dave from #chicago. Visit my city at www.choosechicago.com/things-to-do/ Have a nice day!

It makes 3 captures: 2 under the `tag` group (`@_dave` and `#chicago`) and one under the `link` group (`www.choosechicago.com/things-to-do/`).

You can check it with a regex tester like [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

---

### Explanation

`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` allows you to break your pattern into multiple lines for easier readability. Instead of this:

```
(?'tag'(@|#)(\w|_)+)|(?'link'www\.[\w$-_.+!*'(),]+)
```

You can write this when you turn on the option:

```
(?'tag'(@|\#)(\w|_)+)           # capture @ and # tags into the tag group
|
(?'link'www\.[\w$-_.+!*'(),]+)  # capture hyperlinks, must begin with www
```

`(?'tag'...)` defines a capture group named `tag`, so you can refer to it by name `Groups["tag"]`rather by its positional value `Groups[1]`.

`[\w$-_.+!*'(),]+` defines the list of characters allowed in a URL, which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url). I haven't checked the RFC specs so don't burn me if I missed a few.

Comment: How can I edit it to get links that starts with http://, https:// and www?

Comment: Modify the `link` subpattern. See my updated answer