# Representing ~200 boolean flags in a URL query

Tags: php, url

A public web service accepts configuration options via URL. Each request will use about 20 of the available 200 options, and each one is a `true` or `false` value. The service is stateless and responses will be cached.

Typical example so far:

`http://api.milk.shake/?likesVanilla&likesChocolate=true&likesStrawberry=true`

Assume each value is false unless specified, so shortened to:

`http://api.milk.shake/?likesVanilla&likesChocolate&likesStrawberry`

**The generated URLs are still long and unweildy for 20 options. How can I make them shorter, tidy and keep them valid and usable in the wild?**

*In examples below assume URL rewriting converts URIs into query parameters*

**Approach 1 - Assign a character to each option**

For example `A = likesVanilla`, `B = likesChocolate`, `C = likesStrawberry`

Typical call would be `http://api.milk.shake/ABC`

Fails because [URLs can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and `$-_.+!*'(),` which only covers 73 of the available 200 options.

**Approach 2 - Binary representation**

For example `1 = likesVanilla`, `2 = likesChocolate`, `4 = likesStrawberry`

Typical call would be `http://api.milk.shake/7` (dec or hex maybe)

Where `7 = 1 + 2 + 4 = vanilla + chocolate + strawberry`

Fails because exponentials are exponential - the 63rd option has an array index of `4611686018427387904` and the 64th option breaks PHP unless I'm testing it wrong..

Efficient because parameter order is unified and all similar requests are cached.

**Approach 3 - Grouping with 1 or 2**

I could define groups of options within the URL. This limits the number of available options in each group and allows approach 1 or 2.

For example:

Group 1 options `A = likesVanilla`, `B = likesChocolate`, `C = likesStrawberry`

Group 2 options `A = likesCream`, `B = likesSprinkles`

Typical call would be `http://api.milk.shake/ABC/AB` (first group `/` second group etc)

This is my preferred approach so far. May be answering my own question!

**Approach 4 - Escaped characters**

If characters are [escaped correctly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) then about 220 characters become available.

Typical call would be `http://api.milk.shake/%41%42%43`

Maximum 220 options is not future-proof but could be used with Approach 3. Looks untidy.

Comment: Your POSTing configuration options, so why not use POST instead of GET?

Comment: What about numeric representation of each option, i.e. `http://api.milk.shake/1/6/45/123/7/34/199`?

Comment: @mitkosoft Good idea.. dec or hex as you show would make a good potential answer ;)

Comment: @NoChecksum, yes, hex is even better because you can represent up to 255 options with only 2 symbols (FF).

Comment: @VincentBeltman I think GET requests are simpler, slightly easier to use and (I think) easier to cache. POST is possible if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 could work if you break the options into smaller sets, say 4 sets of 50 bits each.

Just realised you've said as much already as Option 3, hadn't got that far. However, you might be able to use [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to do it as one large integer.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you need it to be a GET? With that many potential parameters it seems like a POST would be a better option and gets around the URL length issue.