# If nCapture match do something in nginx [Regex]

Tags: regex, nginx

I post here even if its probably more a SF question I think it could interest some of you.

Is there a way to tell with Regex to nginx if, for example, the 3rd catpure groupe is match redirect to that else to that ?

Example : 
We have 2 types of URL :

`circuit/asie/indonesie/denpasar-bali/` or `circuit/asie/indonesie/`

and we want to redirect to

`asie/indonesie/denpasar-bali/` or `asie/indonesie/`

Let say we have this Regex : `\w+\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?([^\/]+)?\/`

[Playground here](https://regex101.com/r/hH5rK8/1)

How do you say if match the first case redirect to the first url and match the second redirect to the second ?

Does something like this could work ?

> rewrite    \w+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/     /$1/$2/?$3?/ permanent;

Comment: Why you want it this hard way? How about `rewrite ^/circuit(/asie/.+)$ $1 redirect;`?

Comment: Damn that's a good idea..

Comment: Check this regex :- https://regex101.com/r/pB6qJ4/2

Retrieve the first capturing group as `$1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
rewrite ^(?:.*?/)(.+)$ $1 redirect;
```

For capturing after `n th` group, you can use

```
^(?:(?:.*?\/){n})(.+)$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pB6qJ4/3)

If you want to use allowed characters in `URL` name, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Comment: I goes for this -> `\w+(\/\b(asie|europe|afrique|[Aa]meriques|amerique\-du\-nord|amerique\-du\-sud)\b.+)` But thanks :)

Comment: @Baldráni If you have only `alphabets` and `predefined signs` then its more simple