# Using regex to deal with escape characters in URLs

Tags: python, regex, token, tokenize

I'm in the process of tokenizing strings which contain URLs. Here is the part I use to pick up the URLs:

```
regex_str = [r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+']
```

It picks up "regular" URLs perfectly fine; however some of the URLs look like this:

```
https:\/\/t.co\/c1taPXzi4X
```

How can I modify the regex so that it deals with the escape characters, in order to end up with a complete and clean URL?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url), you can't add a "\" in a url. 
You regex seems ok to me, i've tested [against regxr](http://regexr.com/3dm7s). The only thing I've done is scape the backslashes after http.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, the URLs (or strings rather) with the backslashes are already in my data. So I'm trying to turn

    https:\/\/t.co\/c1taPXzi4X

into 

    http// t.co/c1taPXzi4X

Answer (score 0):

Calling `re.sub` before you apply the regex would work

```
re.sub(r"\\","",r"https:\/\/abc.com\/defg")
```