# URL Encode "." return "." instead of "%2e"

Tags: http

I have a question about url encode/decode. 
When I url decode "%2E", I get ".".
But when i url encode ".", I get "."

I try that in web site like http://www.url-encode-decode.com/.
Can you please tell me why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"." is one of the characters (full list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)) that is allowed to be used in url in unencoded form. So there is no reason to encode it to its hex representation. That's why you are getting:

"." -> encode -> "."

On the other hand every charater CAN be replaced by its hex representation using "%" syntax. This is why you are getting:

"%2E" -> decode -> "."

So you will get this behaviour for every character that is allowed in url in unecoded form:

"a" -> encode -> "a"

"%61" -> decode -> "a"

And this is a valid url for google.com:

http://%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%2E%63%6F%6D