# Slim php framework 3 passing email in argument not working

Tags: php, slim

I am having an error with slim PHP framework 3.

> "The requested resource /try/foo@bar.com/secret was not found on
>   this server."

I am new to slim PHP framework. When I enter email address "*foo@bar*" and password "*secret*" it yields a blank error (i.e. `""`).
When I enter email address "*baz*" and password "*secret2*" then it yields no error message.

I am basically making web service for Android, where the user will enter an email address and password and the required query will be returned in JSON format.

```
$app - > get('/try/{email}/{password}', function($request, $response, $args) {
    include_once('db.php');




    $email = $request - > getAttribute('email');
    echo $email;
    $password = $request - > getAttribute('password');
    echo $password;

    $sql = "select * from user where email='$email' and password='$password'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        header('Content-Type:application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

});
```

Comment: For me it does work. I'm using XAMPP, what are you using? show us your .htaccess file

Comment: I am using wamp .

RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-F
 
RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d
 
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: It works for me, but the difference is that I have the .htaccess file in the public/ directory rather than the root.

Comment: Include an example curl request and response with headers to help to understand what request you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is not a valid character inside an url: (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856809/1172363)

You must create your link with urlencoded email value...

```
$app->urlFor("your_route_name", array("email" => urlencode($mail), "password" => urlencode($password));
```

In your case it would be (for example):

> http://yourserver/try/foo%40bar/your_pass

Comment: Actually I have a problem with addresses with a period " . "

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem by encoding the parameter with Base64 logic.

btoa(criteria)

In the endpoint (mine is PHP) I did a base64decode operation.