# Regex for matching any URL character

Tags: regex

I have come accross a specification that said described a field as :

> Any URL char

And I wanted to validate it on my side via a REGEX.

I searched a bit and, even if I found this great [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) that contains every piece of information I needed, I found it too bad not to have a question asking precisely for the regex, so here I am.

What would be a proper regex matching any URL character ?

**Edit**

I extracted the following regex from what I understood from the specification :

```
[\w\-.~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]
```

So, is this REGEX right and exhaustive or did I miss anything ?

After reading the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), I guess it is simply "all ASCII characters".

Comment: I guess you found the answer for yourserlf :) All I'd add is to make sure there is nothing else in your input: `^[...]*$`

Comment: Yeah, I actually found the answer before asking, I posted the question in case somebody else looked for the same thing. In my case, I wanted the char component and compose it with another regex, but thanks anyways.

Comment: In this case you can post your answer too. Stack Overflow encourages this kind of self-Q&A posts too.

Comment: I actually posted my answer but it got downvoted several times and people asked in comments to remove it and simply edit the question. Thus my editing of the question (because I originally posted both the question and answer)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This wasn't supposed to happen.

Comment: The flag was inappropriate, you should un-delete your answer. But don't post a question inside an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [*Characters* section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2):

> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
> digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
> those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
> URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
> and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
> component's identifying data.

Although there is an indication that only digits, letters and some symbols are supported, you may see a suggested regex to parse a URI at the [*Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) that may actually match pretty every char:

> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
> well-formed URI reference into its components.

> ```
>  ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
> ```

```
   12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
```

What you collected as a `[\w.~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%-]` pattern is too restrictive, unless `\w` is Unicode aware (URI may contain any Unicode letters), then, it might be working more or less for you.

If you plan to match just ASCII URLs, use `^[\x00-\x7F]+$` (any 1+ ASCII symbols) or `^[!-~]+$` (only visible ASCII).