# delete unwanted characters from URL

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, special-characters, encode

I have this variable `String var = class.getSomething` that contains this url `http://www.google.com§°§#[]|£%/^<>` .The output that comes out is this: `http://www.google.comÃ§Â°Â§#[]|Â£%/^<>`. How can i delete that Ã? Thanks!

Comment: Well, why don't you just use an encoding that do it for you? Today it's a `Â` or `Ã`, but tomorrow it may be something else.

Comment: As @Nathan said, its better to use some encoding format than replacing the characters. Because, in future it can be the case where you need the character `Ã` but it gets replaced.

Comment: I don't think that modifying the variable `var` will solve your problem. You don't describe how you produce the output. It may be that the unwanted characters are a result of some misinterpretation of the string's encoding during outout, i.e., they aren't really in the string. So all the var.replace techniques proposed so far are useless.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, it replaces **any** character for empty getting your purpouse.

```
str = str.replace("Â", "");
```

With that you will replace **Â** for nothing, getting the result you want.

Comment: Just to be **this guy**: he asked for `Ã` :D

Comment: I thought was a typo. If you check input string versus output looks like he wants to replace everyone.

Comment: Ha, on my answer below I had also put in the wrong symbol before I submitted :)

Comment: @EliasMP I think he wants to replace both -- just that he don't know it himself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace`

```
var = var.replace("Ã", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

specify the charset as `UTF-8` to get rid of unwanted extra chars :

```
    String var = class.getSomething; 
    var = new String(var.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to delete only that one character or all invalid characters? Otherwise you can check each character with `CharacterUtils.isAsciiPrintable(char ch)`. However, according to RFC 3986 even fewer character are allowed in URLs (alphanumerics and "-_.+=!*'()~,:;/?$@&%", see [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)).

In any case, you have to create a new String object (like with replace in the answer by Elias MP or putting valid characters one by one into a `StringBuilder` and convert it to a String) as Strings are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The string in `var` is output using utf-8, which results in the byte sequence:

```
c2 a7 c2 b0 c2 a7 23 5b 5d 7c c2 a3 25 2f 5e 3c 3e
```

This happens to be the iso-8859-1 encoding of the characters as you see them:

```
 § ° §#[]| £%/^<>
Ã§Â°Â§#[]|Â£%/^<>
```

C2 is the encoding for Â.

I'm not sure how the Ã was produced; it's encoding is C3.

We need the full code to learn how this happened, and a description how the character encoding for text files on your system is configured.

Modifying the variable `var` is useless.