# Why the image is not showing if the name is using another language or special characters?

Tags: php, mysql

Well,

In my database table, I have set the image name as **D@üäö#-09710.jpg**. When I call the table data all data is showing except this image is not showing because of this name!!!

I have checked by inspecting the element and it's showing me:

**src="images/users/D@üäö#-09710.jpg"**

Even the image is successfully uploaded with this name:

**D@üäö#-09710.jpg**

But when I directly view the image using this image URL then the browser showing me:

> The requested URL /xxx/xxxx/images/users/D@Ã¼Ã¤Ã¶ was not
>   found on this server.

Another strange thing is that when I copy the URL from the browser and paste it here then it looks like this:

http://localhost/xxx/xxxx/images/users/D@%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6#.jpg

So it seems like special characters is not reading properly!

**PHP page header is like that:**

```
<?php require_once('admin/init.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">    
    <title>ccrroipr</title>    
    <?php require_once('includes/css.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

**PHP connection:**

```
try {
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/database'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'), array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4"));
    $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

**And the Database Collation is:**

> utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Answer (score 2):

URLs can't contain all of those characters, see [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) for more info. You have to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to transform the URL from `D@üäö#-09710.jpg` to `D%40%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6%23-09710.jpg`. You can keep the filename and database entry as-is (assuming your filesystem can handle the characters), but use urlencode when creating the link.