# Pass View Name to PartialViewResult By Jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I need to pass Views names to `PartialViewResult` from Jquery, single Controller & single `PartialViewResult` method to use entire application,

> working controller code:-

```
    public PartialViewResult addNew(string MenuId)
    {
        return PartialView(@"~/Views/Test/Add.cshtml");
    }
```

> html jquery method:-

```
  $('#btn_add').click(function (e) {
      window.location.href = '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")?MenuId=' + 1;
  });
```

this code working fine but why should we add-code the views name in controller rather pass views name from jquery method, it will be very easy to maintain and very easy method for code

> Expected output:
>   controller code:-

```
    public PartialViewResult addNew(string MenuId, string ViewNames)
    {
        return PartialView("@~/"+ ViewNames);

        //return PartialView(@"~/Views/Test/Add.cshtml");
    }
```

> Expected output:
>   html jquery method:-

```
  $('#btn_add').click(function (e) {
      window.location.href = '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")?MenuId=' + 1 + '&viewname=' + 'Views/Test/Add.cshtml';

  });
```

above code showing An error occurred while processing your request. can anybody share your ideas?..

> I need to pass views name from jquery method with single PartialViewResult method in MVC Controller

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here is you're passing slashes as query string value without using [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), as shown in redirection code below:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")?MenuId=' + 1 + '&viewname=' + 'Views/Test/Add.cshtml';
```

The generated URL from above example will look like this, which is not a valid URL because slash is a reserved character in URL string, hence "*An error occurred while processing your request*" message showed up:

```
/Home/addNew?MenuId=1&viewName=Views/Test/Add.cshtml => invalid trailing slashes
```

To fix this issue, it is necessary to put [`@Url.Encode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.encode?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper so that the slashes are encoded as `%2f` instead:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")?MenuId=' + 1 + '&ViewNames=' + '@Url.Encode("Views/Test/Add.cshtml")';
```

which generates URL-encoded query string:

```
/Home/addNew?MenuId=1&ViewNames=Views%2fTest%2fAdd.cshtml => valid
```

If you're passing the URL from server-side variable/viewmodel string properties, make sure that all special characters passed as query string are encoded first:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")?MenuId=' + @MenuId + '&ViewNames=' + '@Url.Encode(ViewName)';
```

However, I think better to include file path inside action method and pass just viewname without extension if you want to load partial view from same folder, hence avoiding `Url.Encode()` usage:

```
public ViewResult addNew(string MenuId, string ViewNames)
{
    return View(@"~/Views/Test/" + ViewNames + ".cshtml");
}
```

**Notes:**

1) `window.location.href` will reload the whole page, you must use `ViewResult` to do so. If you want to refresh partial view without reloading entire page, use AJAX callback instead.

```js
$('#btn_add').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("addNew", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { MenuId: 1, ViewNames: '@Url.Encode("Views/Test/Add.cshtml")' },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#targetElement').html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
});
```

2) The action method parameters are able to recognize percent encoding characters and revert them to original string.

Related issue:

[Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Comment: your answer is very pretty good, i have to test in development, my thinking always reduce the re-work on every day, so hereafter in MVC don't need multiple Controller

Comment: single controller & single method is enough for entire MVC application