# Sending python computed values to telegram

Tags: python-3.7, telegram-bot

I just created a telegram bot in python and I want to be sending the results of the data I analyse in python to a telegram channel in a special format, here is an sample of what I would like to send:

```
a = '#N' + game_to_analyse['Id_number'] + ': ' +'54783355882'
```

But when I try to send this value 'a' to my telegram channel, I only get `"` as message on my phone or telegram desktop app.
What is the issue?

Comment: P.S. I just realized its the '#' that is causing the problem, is there any way to remedy to this without removing the '#'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` is probably [messing with your url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856809/5625547)

Solution:

[`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) the query params:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

data = {
    'text' : '#N12345:6789',
    'chat_id': myChatId,
    'parse_mode' : 'MarkDown'
}
encodedData = urlencode(data, quote_via=quote_plus)

url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?' + encodedData
response = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: works great, is there a similar way to encode emojis for inter-compatibility on android and iOS?