# Getting <Response [200]> on Python when sending to Telegram a string containing the plus sign "+"

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Sending messages to a Telegram channel from Python is quite easy, just create a Telegram bot, save its token id and add the bot to the channel as admin, then the Python code is

```
import requests
TOKEN = "..." # bot token ID to access the HTTP API
CHANNEL_ID = "..." # for example @durov
MSG = "..."
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + CHANNEL_ID + "&text=" + MSG
requests.post(url)
```

However, when using for example `MSG = "test+8"`, the message sent to the Telegram channel is `test 8` (with a whitespace instead of the plus sign) and on Python I get the following output

```
<Response [200]>
```

I tried to replace the plus sign with the minus sign and that works, but what is the problem with the plus sign? Is it a special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with URL encoding - you can circumvent the "missrepersented" + by urlencode your `MSG` yourself:

```
import urllib.parse
MSG = 'message + 42'
enc = urllib.parse.quote(MSG)
print(enc)
```

Output:

```
message%20%2B%204
```

and send this encoded message.

See f.e. [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) for more informations on that.

> According to [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) the
> character `+` belongs to reserved characters of
>
> ```
>   sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"   
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```
>
> and needs to be quoted when used in the query part of an uri.

Comment: Thank you it works! I still get `<Response [200]>` in Python, is it ok?

Comment: @soundwave - see Http-Status-Codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes   200[OK] is the answer your httpcall gets if all is OK.