# How to handle Square Brackets [] in Jmeter Request

Tags: api, jmeter, httprequest

There is a case to handle Square Brackets [] in Jmeter Request
Ex : /api/v1/user/userlist/user[id]/7203/user[roles]/coe

How to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have characters like `[` and `]` in URL Path, see [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) question for comprehensive information

You need to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP):

- `[` - to `%5B`
- `]` - to `%5D`

If your URL path comes from external source you can do this automatically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code:

```
sampler.setPath(sampler.getPath().replaceAll('\\[','%5B').replaceAll('\\]','%5D'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the implementation type to Java in the HTTP Request Sampler

working fine....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfKaL.png)