# Nginx location blocks syntax

Tags: nginx, url, xss, nginx-location

I'm trying to return 400 status if someone includes this character '<' anywhere in the url request, for example the request might look like

https://example.com/adfg<script

I tried the following in **Nginx** location block, but obviously this is not how it works,

```
location /*<* {
      return 400;
}
```

What's the right syntax that i need to write please.

Answer (score 0):

"<" characters is not allowed in a url. Therefore you can't use it, maybe you want to use the url encoded version: "%3C".

Check: [Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Comment: Ok great, and how would i write the location block please for '%3C' if it came anywhere in the url