# How to copy http link under cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to copy link (http URL) that is under cursor. I'm aware that I can copy the whole line with `ctrl-c` when nothing is selected, but in my case links are in the middle of text.

Example: `wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page - the great encyclopedia`

VScode recognize it's a link because it allows to open it, but doesn't offer to copy it to clipboard

[image]

I've searched for an extension to achieve this but I didn't found unfortunately.

Comment: `http://https://` is not a valid URL protocol, thus VSC uses a simple regex

Comment: Whooops, copy/paste error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-with-surround)

Use the command: `selectby.regex`

### Call by command palette

If you call the command from the Command Palette define the regex in the setting: `selectby.regexes`.

In `setting.json` add:

```json
    "selectby.regexes": {
      "selectHTTPs": {
        "surround": "https?://[\\w;,/?:@&=+$\\-.!~*'()#]+",
        "copyToClipboard": true
      }
    }
```

### Call with a shortkey

If you call the command with a key binding you can add these arguments to the key binding:

In `keybindings.json` add:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "command": "selectby.regex",
        "args": {
            "surround": "https?://[\\w;,/?:@&=+$\\-.!~*'()#]+",
            "copyToClipboard": true
        }
      }
```

This uses a very basic HTTP(S) URL regex.

The selection is also copied to the clipboard, no need to use `Ctrl+C`

Maybe somebody on the internet has written a more elaborate URL regex.

Or you can browse the VSC source to locate the `DocumentLinkProvider` that scans for URLs.

**Edit**

I looked for allowed characters and adjusted the regex. I did not know `()` are allowed.

[Characters allowed in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/url-encoded-characters-reference

Comment: Thanks ! This works  Note: as settings file is a Json file, backslash must be protected:         "surround": "https?://[^\\s]+"

Comment: @BrunoDuyé thanks for the edit and double backslash, I looked for allowed characters and modified the regex, I don't know if `:` is allowed outside the protocol